# How to allow connections only over proxy in Java?

Tags: java, networking, proxy

I have a Java application which needs to use proxies. The proxy is set with System.setProperty, but if I want to test my application, the properties seems to be ignored if they are invalid. I tried a local installed proxy and the network traffic from my application is redirected to this proxy. But if I enter a wrong port, I can still load a page in a JavaFX WebView. Is it possible only to allow a connection over proxies to test if everything works fine?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set following properties, this could may be force the java application to use proxy.

https://gist.github.com/Barlog-M/ae41a62fa54f3b6f7e64

Comment: The problem is that I can set the proxy but I can load a site in JavaFX WebView even if the proxy can't be reached